# Hibernate isolation levels vs database isolation levels

Tags: hibernate, db2, isolation-level

If Hibernate is used as the ORM tool and DB2 as the database in Hibernate we can define Isolation levels and DB2 has its own isolation levels. What is the benefit that we get by defining the isolation levels in hibernate vs using the database isolation levels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate acts as an abstraction layer across databases; it would be preferable to use Hibernate's isolation level if you wanted to specify the same isolation levels for multiple supported databases (to the extent that the databases support that isolation level; for instance, Oracle won't implement uncommitted reads).

Hibernate can specify an isolation level for individual queries by appending a WITH clause. That will take precedence over DB2's default for isolation level. So you can pick an isolation level for the database, then allow tweaking the level for individual queries generated by Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same thing. Hibernate sets the isolation level on the JDBC Connections it uses to connect to DB2, so that DB2 uses that isolation level for these connections.

So, the level of transaction isolation is handled by the database.

Comment: Thanks. Then what is the benefit that we get by defining at Hibernate can we leave so that it is handled at the DB level. Is there any scenario where it would be better to define it at the hibernate

Comment: I don't know anything about DB2, but I assume that if you set an isolation level in the database configuration, it becomes the default for all the connections to that database. Setting it at the hibernate level allows setting an isolation level for your Hibernate application only, which might be different from the default level set on the database.

Comment: If the isolation level that is defined at the hibernate is different from what is defined at the database then which one would take precedence.

Comment: I assume the one set on the connection would take precedence. But once again, I don't know anything about DB2. What does its documentation say about the isolation level configuration?